# Removing bibliography fields

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, bibliographystyle

I'm using KOMA's `scrartcl` document to create a short paper where I've included some references.
I'm using

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}
```

at the end to print the bibliography. Unfortunately, a field called `tex.ids:...` keeps appearing.

**How can I remove that field for every entry?**

I have tried using

```
\usepackage[
   backend=biber,
   style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}
```

but I have errors about not being able to find the bibliography.

I'm using Overleaf.

Comment: Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering. For the creation of a MWEB (minimal working example with Bibliography) see also: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/231952

Comment: Have you tried changing `\addbibresource{references}` to `\addbibresource{references.bib}`?

Comment: Please edit your posting to show an entry that has a field called `tex.ids`.

Comment: Generally bibliography styles (no matter if BibTeX or Biber) will ignore fields they don't know. Off the top of my head I'm not aware of any style that knows `tex.ids`, so something else is going on. Presumably the `tex.ids` data is exported into some field that is known and does get printed, but without an example of a `.bib` entry, it's impossible to help properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `tex.ids` field wasn't a field *per se* but the text inside the notes.

It appears from the Zotero export (I import the bibliography into Overleaf from Zotero), but it doesn't appear in the Zotero app. After looking at the .bib file, I saw that it was in the note fields.

The solution I took first was to remove every non-useful field when setting the biblatex package options.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,%
    style=numeric,%
    sorting=none,%
    giveninits=true,%
    eprint=false,%
    url=false,doi=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
```

Finally, I used the commands below in the preamble to clear the notes field at every item in the bibliography-

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{note}%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a BibLaTeX question, but since googling `tex.ids` brings you here, I also encountered this issue with Overleaf/Zotero BBT using BibTeX and solved it by adding the following IEEEtran.bst (which was suggested [here on the Zotero forum](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/6674/zotero-extra-bibtex-note-how-not-to-show) more than a decade ago.):

```
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
#1
{ "" }
{…}
if$
}
```