# How can I print my bibliography without the notes I have in every reference entry?

Tags: bibtex

I used a reference manager for my bibliography and added personal notes to all my refernces to organise them. Now using bibtex (bibliography style unsrt) these notes appear in my bibliography. How can I exclude the notes from my bibliography without having to alter every entry in my reference library?

Comment: Does this solve your problem?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591899/90297

Comment: No, that doesn't work for me. It leads toerros without removign the note

Comment: In that case, it would help a lot if you could post a Minimal Working Example (MWE) a short code that starts with `\documentclass{` and ends with `\end{document}` so that we could recreate the environment you're using and see exactly how to answer your question